# Multiple arguments in Clojure anonymous functions

Tags: clojure

I have difficulty in using `keep-indexed` with multiple arguments:

Using:

```
(keep-indexed #(if (= %1 3) %2)  [1 2 3 4 5])
```

I can get the value with index 3, namely `(4)`.

If the index should be given as an argument, for example for index 3:

```
(keep-indexed #(if (= %1 ???) %2) 3 [1 2 3 4 5])
```

How should I modify the ???-part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to factor it out as `keep-indexed` expects a two argument function.

```
(defn my-nth [index coll] (keep-indexed #(if (= %1 index) %2) coll))

(my-nth 3 [1 2 3 4 5])
;=> (4)
```

If you are just trying to access by index, then for a vector

```
(get [1 2 3 4 5] 3) ;=> 4
```

Or indeed simply

```
([1 2 3 4 5] 3) ;=> 4
```

If you, say wanted the values at index 1 and 3.

```
(map (partial get [1 2 3 4 5]) [1 3])
;=> (2 4)
```

Or, if you like

```
(map [1 2 3 4 5] [1 3])
;=> (2 4)
```

For a list or sequence type, use `nth`.